# Unable to have javax.ws.rs.core.Response entity on client side

Tags: java, web-services, entity, response

I am developping a Web Service with Jersey and `javax.ws.rs` library.

My problem is that I have a server with this code :

```
Response response = Response
                .status(OK)
                .entity(json)
                .build();
```

then `response.getEntity()` is my `json` (no `{}` )

But in the client side I have this (`WebTarget target`):

```
Response request= target.path("Server/getJSON")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .get();
```

then `request.readEntity(JSONObject.class)` = `{}`

DO you have some reason why ?

Comment: Your resource method should probably set the returned content type, for example with `Response response = Response.ok(json, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).build();`.  The resource method should also have a `@Produces` annotation which includes `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`.

Comment: This is what I do ;) Still problem